# Good Books on Complex Multiplication (on Elliptic Curves)

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I don't know anything yet about Complex Multiplication (on elliptic Curves).
Do you know good introductory books on the Matter?
I'm especially looking for a proof that the following terms are algebraic integers whenever $\tau$ is a quadratic irrationality:
$$\frac{E_4(\tau)}{\eta^8(\tau)},\quad\frac{E_6(\tau)}{\eta^{12}(\tau)}\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt{D}\cdot\frac{E_2(\tau)-\frac{3}{\pi\Im(\tau)}}{\eta^4(\tau)}$$
Here $\eta$ denotes the Dedekind $\eta$-Function, $E_k$ are the Eisenstein series of weight $k$, and $D=B^2-4AC$ where $A\tau^2+B\tau+C=0$

**Edit:** As @Mathmo123 commented (Thank you!!!), the first expression is a root of the polynomial $P(X)=X^3-1728J(\tau)$ and the second is a root of $Q(X)=X^2-1728+1728J(\tau)$, where $1728J(\tau)\in\mathbb Z$. Thus it only remains to prove that the third expression is an algebraic integer.

**Edit:** I verified numerically that the sixth power of the third expression is integral for all Discriminants with class number $1$, but I don't see how I can prove it. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the books mentioned by @gandalf61 or by @Mathmo123 ... -> but this is another topic, moved to another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795300/how-to-prove-that-the-values-of-eisenstein-series-e-2-are-algebraic-integers).

Comment: Just check good books on elliptic curves. There are many references given at this site. There are also posts about what makes complex multiplication so interesting, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762947/why-say-complex-multiplication-of-elliptic-curves-is-beautiful).

Comment: I really enjoyed [these lecture notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/ramanujanconstant.pdf) by Ben Green. I'm not sure if they cover the exact forms in your question, but they do cover the integrality of the $j$-invariant in detail. (Your first two expressions are just its square and cubed root.) Alternatively, there is Silverman's Advanced Topics

Comment: David Cox' "Primes of the form $p = x^2 + ny^{2}$" has a nice section on complex multiplication. However, I can't remember if it has precisely the results you're looking for. Nevertheless, it was a good place for me to start learning about CM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chapter on CM theory in Silverman's "Advanced Topics", mentioned in @gandalf61's answer, is a standard introductory account. However, given your recent questions, I suspect you are looking for a textbook with a more complex-analytic flavour, emphasising links with elliptic-function theory, reciprocity laws for singular moduli, etc. In that case, you might like to have a look at Reinhard Schertz's 2010 book "[Complex Multiplication](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mE_EIma4iUcC&printsec=frontcover)".

Answer (score 2):

Standard introductory texts are:

- *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* - Silverman and Tate
- *Elliptic Curves* - Milne
- *Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms* - Koblitz

More advanced texts are:

- *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* - Silverman
- *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* - Silverman

Comment: Given that at least 3 of these books barely touch on complex multiplication, I'm not really sure what this answer gives.

Comment: The questioner asks about modular forms as well as complex multiplication. But by all means feel free to improve on my suggestions :)

Comment: Only one of these books contains anything substantial about modular forms. These are 5 serious texts, of which only the last is useful for the problem at hand. The OP could easily waste a lot of time obtaining and reading through each of the first four. On what basis did you recommend these texts? Have you read them?